# My pandas dataframe all of a sudden won't show me decimal numbers? Did something change in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, floating-point

I have a number of dataframes that I have created that all values are supposed to be 3 decimal places. This is what it was made to do and it's what it was doing last week.
Now all of a sudden when I ran my Jupyter notebook this morning, it's rounding everything in all my dataframes to whole numbers.

I have no idea why. Was there some change to pandas, is there a setting I can change? When I print the dtypes of all the columns, it says they're float, I tried just using round on the dataframe but it didn't do anything. Here is what I mean:

what it looked like just last week:

```
    Jan 2021   Feb 2021   Jul 2021  Aug 2021
A      0.7      0.938       0.80      0.75
B      0.3      0.062       0.08      0.20
C      0.0       0.0        0.12      0.05
D      0.0       0.0         0.0      0.0
```

I reverted back to a checkpoint from last week in Jupyter notebooks and was able to see when it was last run and could see these numbers, but then even when I ran it after reverting back to the old checkpoint, this new change was there and this is what it now looks like (both when I ran it this morning not expecting this issue and when I reran the previous version which didn't have this issue just a few days ago):

```
     Jan 2021   Feb 2021   Jul 2021  Aug 2021
A       1          1         1           1
B       0          0         0           0
C       0          0         0           0
D       0          0         0           0
```

So I'm wondering if something changed in Pandas? Has anyone else had this happen? Also important to note when I print each of the lists these columns are made from those values still show the correct numbers from the first dataframe, with 3 decimal places

edit:

code used to create a column of the dataframe:

```
deca=round((len(decemberprediction[decemberprediction['COST_TYPE_A']==1])/len(decemberprediction)),3)
decb=round((len(decemberprediction[decemberprediction['COST_TYPE_B']==1])/len(decemberprediction)),3)
decc=round((len(decemberprediction[decemberprediction['COST_TYPE_C']==1])/len(decemberprediction)),3)
    
decd=round((len(decemberprediction[decemberprediction['COST_TYPE_D']==1])/len(decemberprediction)),3)
```

deccontractmix=[deca, decb,decc,decd]
print(deccontractmix)

which returns [0.643, 0.25, 0.036, 0.0] as it should

then to create the dataframe, I have all the other month columns that also have that result list with their own values as well, and then do:

```
predcontractmix=pd.DataFrame([[jancontractmix[0],febcontractmix[0],julcontractmix[0],augcontractmix[0],sepcontractmix[0],octcontractmix[0],novcontractmix[0],deccontractmix[0]], 
                         [jancontractmix[1],febcontractmix[1],julcontractmix[1],augcontractmix[1],sepcontractmix[1],octcontractmix[1],novcontractmix[1],deccontractmix[1]],
                         [jancontractmix[2],febcontractmix[2],julcontractmix[2],augcontractmix[2],sepcontractmix[2],octcontractmix[2],novcontractmix[2],deccontractmix[2]],
                         [jancontractmix[3],febcontractmix[3],julcontractmix[3],augcontractmix[3],sepcontractmix[3],octcontractmix[3],novcontractmix[3],deccontractmix[3]]], columns=['Jan 2021', 'Feb 2021','Jul 2021','Aug 2021','Sept 2021', 'Oct 2021', 'Nov 2021','Dec 2021'])
predcontractmix.index=contractlabels

predcontractmix=pd.merge(predcontractmix,contractmix, left_on=predcontractmix.index, right_on=contractmix.index, how='outer')
predcontractmix=predcontractmix.rename(columns={'key_0':'Contract Type'})
predcontractmix=predcontractmix.set_index('Contract Type')
print('\nContract Mix                                                                       percent,median')
predcontractmix.head(6)
```

the merge is a similar dataframe that has the same rows but just with 2 ytd columns

Comment: Also important to note, I have not changed a single line of code in this notebook between last week when it worked as expected and now

Comment: `pd.options.display.float_format`

Comment: Have you tried this? `%precision %.3f` then rerun the dataframes

Comment: Is this data generated by dividing two integers?

Comment: It sounds like you have display precision set to 0 somewhere. Code that can reproduce this behaviour would be helpful. Are there environment settings that have changed etc? [Setting startup options in Python/IPython environment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment)

Comment: @XXavier, isn't that for printing strings? When I print the types of my columns they say float64

Comment: @rm-fme yes, I will edit to show you the code I used to create one of the rows in the dataframe, I tried to be cautious about what I provided as it is for work

Comment: @XXavier I added that in and didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue, answering for anyone in the future who has the same issue:

I tried all of these and they didn't work for me:

- adding pd.options.display.float_format to the top of my notebook
- adding %precision %.3f to the top of my notebook
- adding pd.set_option("precision", 5) to the top of my notebook

What finally worked for me was adding this to the top of my notebook:

- pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format